# How to install mono in centOS7 aarch64

Tags: installation, mono

How to install mono in centOS 7 aarch64? The official download page only support x86_x64.

Does mono support RHEL 7 arm64?

[official download page](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-centos)

Can this package be installed into centOS7 aarch64?

[image: archlinux arm mono]

If yes, how to install or build it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: mono **aarch64** is in the EPEL.repo : 17 mono packages https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/aarch64/Packages/m/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to install mono in centOS 7 aarch64

`mono` **aarch64** is in the EPEL.repo : 17 mono packages  https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/aarch64/Packages/m/

EPEL : Extra packages for Enterprise Linux https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Mono website](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-centos), only x86_64 is available for CentOS/RHEL 7.